# Simplify nested Mono<Either<Error, Object>> expressions kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reactive

I'm new to reactive framework, and got a problem that has this logic:

```
fun someFunction(someRequest: Request): Mono<Object> {
    return functionA.flatMap {
      when {
        it.isLeft -> Object(errors=it.swap().toOption().toList().first()).toMono()
        else -> it.toOption.map {
          functionB.flatMap {
            when {
              it.isLeft -> Object(errors=it.swap().toOption().toList().first()).toMono()
              else -> it.toOption.map {
                Object(someresults).toMono()
              }.getOrElse { Mono.empty() }
            }
          }
        }.getOrElse { Mono.empty() }
      }
    }
}
```

where functionA returns Mono<Either<Error, SomeObj>>, functionB returns Mono<Either<Error, SomeOtherObj>>

Is there a way to simplify this nested structure, instead of doing multiple whens?
The return type is Mono and what I'm trying to do is run functionA, then if error, exit early with the Object(errors=...), otherwise, continue and run functionB and so forth.

Update: Thanks! I think to use `fold` would be something like:

```
fun someFunction(someRequest: Request): Mono<Object> {
    return functionA.flatMap {
        it.fold(
            { Object(errors=it).toMono() },
            {
                functionB.flatMap{
                ... 
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `when` expression on `Either` you can use `fold`/`foldLeft` method. try to visualize as list of actions

Comment: thanks! I think I got it :)